# How to define a userdefined Type in Rehosted Wokrlfow Designer

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

If a type is already included in the referenced assemblies of the rehosted workflow designer, and ready to be selected, why do I get a workflow Designer compiler error when I define a variable of that type?
And how do I define a userdefined Type in my C# code or the rehosted workflow to make it recognizable by the workflow designer.

Comment: That doesn't make sense... a little bit of code and `.ToString()` on the error would help clarify...

Comment: I am not sure what code to include though. It is a lot of line of code of a re-hosted workflow designer. thank you for concurring that this does not make sense.